# Automatically return first item of an array if there is only one

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to return automatically the first object of an array is there is only one inside, without using an if condition?

Basically what I'm doing right know is

```
if (isNestedElement) {
    return generatedElement;
} else if (generatedElement.length === 1) {
    return generatedElement[0];
}
```

And I'm trying to simplify it like

```
if (isNestedElement) {
    return generatedElement;
}
```

But the second return must be and object when there is only 1 object inside the array.

I don't know anything to do it simply in JavaScript, any idea?

**Examples**

If my array is looking like

```
[
   {foo: foo, bar: bar},
   {two: two, three: three},
   {four: four, baz: baz},
   {five: five},
]
```

I want to return

```
[
   {foo: foo, bar: bar},
   {two: two, three: three},
   {four: four, baz: baz},
   {five: five},
]
```

By when my array is looking like

```
[
   {foo: foo, bar: bar},
]
```

I want to return

```
{foo: foo, bar: bar}
```

Comment: please add some examples. does the first one work? what is with the last else part which is not given?

Comment: Add your json data too.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an if statement, your logic clearly uses a conditional?

Comment: Why would there be? Doing that is usually bad design anyway…

Comment: I think it is better to have an uniform resultset... ;-)

Comment: if you do this, you will have to add one more if to check whether its array or object, better to use array.

Comment: You haven't explained why using an `if` condition is so toxic.

Comment: Everything is working well right know, but i'm just trying to find if there is a way to simply this code, instead having a lot of if statements.

Comment: btw, what is `isNestedElement` doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz `isNestedElement` is just a boolean to check if the current generated elements (it can be anything `a`/`p`/...) must be inside the parent one. My function allow creation of any HTML element inside VueJS virtual dom from a basic object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
if (isNestedElement) {
  return generatedElement.length === 1? generatedElement[0] : generatedElement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and check for the length of the array.

```
return generatedElement.length === 1
    ? generatedElement[0]
    : generatedElement;
```

Comment: `generatedElement[1]`?